# Is there a way to reduce multiple type parameters?

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I have a very generic heavy class where i am testing differents approach to a problem and this class is used in a lot different places and everytime i change the number of type parameters i have to fix errors everywhere i use the type even where i dont use that class genericity

```
public class HeavyGen<TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3, ETC>{...}

//now anywhere else i have to do either this and refactor my code at each 
//change in the number of type parameters

public HeavyGen<?,?,?,?> func(){...}

//or this but @SupressWarning seem like a dirty fix

@SupressWarning
public HeavyGen func(){...}
```

**So:** is there a way to be able to change the number of type parameter of `HeavyGen` while not having to refactor code in places that dont use it genericity?

Ideas I had:

- using a class type that would """encapsulate""" the type parameters, like `TypeBag<TYPE1,TYPE2,TYPE3,ETC>` ans then use `Container<BAG extends TypeBag>`, but it doesn't seem to work
- since those type parameters are mostly used inside the class, do some trick with methods type parameters to pass them around. I haven't managed to make it work so far either.
- having a nested class inheritance system (like `<CHILD extends Container> CHILD.Inner`) but Java doesn't seem to like that either (the more i think of it the more i would love to be able to do this :D )

Comment: *How do I keep the number of type parameters in Container<...> restrained/in control? (aka no mass refactoring later)* -> Please explain what you mean with mass-refactorings, and how do you mean *in control*, control them by code or simply by javadoc etc?

Comment: @LinosaysReinstateMonica i mean that if i need to change the type parameters of Container, everywhere i used the Container type (for a function return or parameter, without requiring these types in particular for example) i would have to change the code of that function to fix it type parameters

by in control i mean that i wont have to do that

Comment: Well, you cannot be surprised that the communicty downvote it. Your description is so messy that it really is not possible to understand what you want. *Either* describe your **very original** problem (without the fancy stuff, maybe it's an x-y problem), or *extract* the **very technical core** of your problem and make it as simple as posssible. Now you are talking about too many things but on the very detailed technical level. It is impossible to comprehend the whole mess.

Comment: @HonzaZidek oh i see what you mean. i edited my question, hope its better now

Comment: Your last edit is **good**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply rename your `Container<...>` to `AbstractContainer<...>` and extract a non-generic `Container` interface from it:

```
public interface Container {
    // put non-generic methods here
}
```

```
public abstract class AbstractContainer<...> implements Container {
    // put generic methods here
}
```

Now client code can use `Container` without carrying about generics, and implementations can extend `AbstractContainer<...>` and still be able to use/implement generic methods.